# how to reload windows with url update in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have three buttons so when i click on button1 then that button function call and store the string value to the  **Endpoint** and windows should reload with updated data.. so the updated url should be **https://api_url_here/national**

but the problem is windows is not relaoding with updated value

```js
var btn1 = document.querySelector(".btn1");
var endpoint = [];
console.log(endpoint);
fetch(`https://api_url_here/${endpoint}`)
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    } else {
      throw new Error("Something went wrong");
    }
  })
  .then((newsData) => {
   console.log(newsData);
    })

btn1.addEventListener("click", function () {
    endpoint = "national";
    console.log(endpoint);
});
```

```html
        <div class="menu">
          <button class="btn1">national</button>
          <button class="btn2">buisness</button>
          <button class="btn3">politics</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to use querySelectorAll to get all buttons and bind event to each one of them:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-button");
function fetchData(endpoint) {
    fetch(`https://api_url_here/${endpoint}`).then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        } else {
            throw new Error("Something went wrong");
        }
    })
    .then((newsData) => {
        console.log(newsData);
    });
}

buttons.forEach(b => b.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    fetchData(event.target.getAttribute("data-value"));
}));
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu"> 
    <button class="menu-button" data-value="national">national</button> 
    <button class="menu-button" data-value="business">business</button> 
    <button class="menu-button" data-value="politics">politics</button> 
</div>
```

Comment: i need to add different value to each button

Comment: @VickyPawar: Updated the answer. Check now. You can add data-value attribute to each button and read them in JS using getAttribute

Comment: Updated the class name as well to keep it a bit meaningful. Hope it helps

Comment: with your solution url is updating now but windows in load reloading.. i mean api data in not changing in browser but url is changing is console.log

Answer (score 1):

You should call your API *after* button click. Currently, it's being called *before* that happens.

I suggest wrapping the `fetch()` call in a function to make your code more universal. Also, you can attach an event to all of your buttons and call the new function like this:

```js
var btn1 = document.querySelectorAll(".btn1");

btn1.forEach(function (btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    callAPI(e.target.value);
  });
});

function callAPI(endpoint) {
  fetch(`https://api_url_here/${endpoint}`)
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    } else {
      throw new Error("Something went wrong");
    }
  })
  .then((newsData) => {
   console.log(newsData);
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
          <button class="btn1" value="national">national</button>
          <button class="btn1" value="business">buisness</button>
          <button class="btn1" value="politics">politics</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: what if i have different value in each button.. like when i click one btn1 it should store Nations to endpoint and btn2 it should store buisness and same for btn3